# Standard New User Welcome Messages

Tags: discussion, new-users

What is the best message to notify a new user with an issue with their post (via a comment) while posting a(n)...

1. Challenge (unclear specs/questionable)
2. Challenge (duplicate)
3. Challenge (off-topic)
4. Answer to a challenge.

Comment: Do you mean what to say in a comment notifying the user of an issue with their post?

Comment: @AlexA. Yes. I'll specify that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always start by welcoming the new user. It's best to make users feel welcome in the community and not to sound hostile. I also always recommend the Sandbox (especially now that there's no rep limit).

For specific issues:

- Unclear

  > Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges! This challenge could use a bit of clarification. For example, (insert specific issues here). I recommend posting future challenges to the `[Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)` where they can get meaningful feedback before being posted to the main site.
- Duplicate

  > Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges! Unfortunately this challenge is too similar to `[Challenge Name](link to existing challenge)` to warrant a separate post. I recommend posting future challenges to the `[Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)` where they can get meaningful feedback before being posted to the main site.
- Off-topic

  > Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges! This site is for programming competitions, not for general programming questions. For those you can try `[Stack Overflow|Super User|Other SE Site](link)`, but make sure to check out their Help Center first to ensure your question is on topic. Thanks!
- Answer

  > Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges! This doesn't quite meet the requirements of the challenge since [specific issues]. ***OR*** Submissions on this site must [specific issue with link to meta].

Comment: I suppose a default text specifically for ungolfed answers would come in handy. I'll see if I can write one up later.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That would be great! I can make this CW if you think that'd be best.